# curl works, sockets fail for most domains and IPs

Tags: php, homebrew, php-stream-wrappers

My local mac host is unable to use PHP's file stream wrappers in any form for HTTP requests (which is required to use composer, etc).

If I request the exact same resource with the curl driver, everything is fine. Here's two programs I copied directly out of the PHP documentation:

This one is curl, it works every time without fail.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

This one uses fopen, and always fails after the 60 second default in `php.ini`. This failure is the same with file_get_contents or any other file stream based approach.

```
<?php
$opts = [ 'http'=> [ 'method' => "GET" ]];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r', false, $context);
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

This results in:

```
Warning: fopen(http://www.example.com): 
failed to open stream: 
    Operation timed out in ...php on line ...
```

I've tried PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.3.

Here's a sample of my ini file with reduced settings:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
auto_append_file =
auto_globals_jit = On
auto_prepend_file =
default_charset = "UTF-8"
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_socket_timeout = 60
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
engine = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731"
file_uploads = On
html_errors = On
implicit_flush = Off
output_buffering = 4096
```

And for streams in `php --info`

```
$ php --info  | grep -i stream
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
libXML streams => enabled
mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
```

Some facts:

1. I installed this with `brew`.
2. The issue is present with all URLs
3. We know it's not a firewall (curl works)
4. `allow_url_fopen` is `On`
5. Only happens when opening a stream
6. Multiple installs of PHP have this issue.
7. Even if connecting with fstreamopen `$fp = fsockopen("1.1.1.1", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);` there's the same delay.
8. If removing the domain name and using an IP like 1.1.1.1 directly, the problem is gone. However, when I request `php -r "copy('http://54.36.53.46', 'composer-setup.php');"` the same timeout failure returns.

Comment: Have you tried including a `header` key/value in your `$opts`?

Comment: @l'L'l Doesn't improve anything. I've just also discovered if I change directly to `fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)` it still fails this way.

Comment: What error is it giving with `fsockopen`? Maybe try the first example on this page and see what it returns: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: It's also a timeout. I'm going to update the question with more information.

Comment: I checked my `php --info` and the only difference between yours and mine is I have `sslv3`... whereas yours doesn't.